# Unable to assign the value read from Arduino into my Visual Studio control but Value is getting displayed in MsgBox in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arduino

Unable to assign the value read from Arduino into my Visual Studio control but Value is getting displayed in MsgBox in Visual Studio. I have 3 Forms here...Form1 has 2 buttons which direct to 2 different forms each....In my Form 2 i am opening my serial Port and reading the data from my arduino....The data is correctly displaying in the MSG box of VisualStudio(IDE i am using to create a GUI for user) but the same data i am not able to assign to any of my controls such as label or textbox..it says the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lblCurrentHumid' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

```
Arduino Code
#include "DHT.h"
#include <Servo.h>

#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302), AM2321
#define DHTPIN 2

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo

String mySt, crop = "Rice";
float h,t;
int m,i=1,pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position
char choise = 0,myChar = 0;

void setup() 
{
      Serial.begin(9600);
      dht.begin();
      //myservo.attach(8);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
      while (!Serial)
      {
          ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
      }
}


void loop() 
{
      if (i == 1)
      {
          if(Serial.available() > 0) 
          {
              mySt = Serial.readString();
           }   
      }    
      Serial.print(mySt);
      if (mySt == "One")
      {
        Serial.print("yoo");
        i++;
      }

}
```

```
VS Code

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FinalYearProject
{
    public partial class Suggession : Form
    {
        String msg, temp, humi, mois, Result, choise;
        public Suggession()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Suggession_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox("Bfr opening");
            serialPort1.Open();
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox("after opening");
            serialPort1.WriteLine("One");
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox("after writing");
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox("dfghjk");
            msg = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox(msg); \\My Vaule "One" is displaying in the MsgBox
            txtSelectedPort.Text = msg;\\But when i assign it here i am getting the Cross Threading Error 

        }

    } 
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are using multiple forms  (along with serial port) and can get cross-threading issues.  You need to use Invoke to resolve these issues.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: i read the link mentioned above, but couldnt get how to apply it to my code......if u can help me with that it will be really helpfull @jdweng

Comment: I had same issue on Friday after I answered your posting.  The issue is writing to a control on the form from inside the serial port receive event.  My solution is at work which I can post tomorrow.  You canuse one of Jon Skeet's solutions at this webpage : https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/events.html.

Comment: Sure sir, Will go through link mentioned and eagerly waiting for your  response sir! Thanks in advance @jdweng